# Comparing multiple classifiers: Nemenyi + Holm test in R

Tags: r

I try to reproduce the results from (1) as a newbie to R. Table 6 are the AUCs of 4 classifier on 14 data sets:

```
auc <- matrix(c(
  0.763 , 0.768 , 0.771 , 0.798 ,
  0.599 , 0.591 , 0.590 , 0.569 ,
  0.954 , 0.971 , 0.968 , 0.967 ,
  0.628 , 0.661 , 0.654 , 0.657 ,
  0.882 , 0.888 , 0.886 , 0.898 ,
  0.936 , 0.931 , 0.916 , 0.931 ,
  0.661 , 0.668 , 0.609 , 0.685 ,
  0.583 , 0.583 , 0.563 , 0.625 ,
  0.775 , 0.838 , 0.866 , 0.875 ,
  1.000 , 1.000 , 1.000 , 1.000 ,
  0.940 , 0.962 , 0.965 , 0.962 ,
  0.619 , 0.666 , 0.614 , 0.669 ,
  0.972 , 0.981 , 0.975 , 0.975 ,
  0.957 , 0.978 , 0.946 , 0.970),
  nrow = 14,
  byrow = TRUE,
  dimnames = list(1 : 14, c("C4.5", "C4.5+m", "C4.5+cf", "C4.5+m+cf"))
)

Friedman chi-squared = 10.952, df = 3, p-value = 0.01199
```

The paper says (page 13) chi-square = 9.28 and FF=3.69. Where do I get this value from the test above?

Next step is the Nemenyi for which I used the `PMCMR` lib.

```
> library(PMCMR)
> posthoc.friedman.nemenyi.test(auc)

    Pairwise comparisons using Nemenyi multiple comparison test 
             with q approximation for unreplicated blocked data 

data:  auc 

          C4.5  C4.5+m C4.5+cf
C4.5+m    0.089 -      -      
C4.5+cf   0.972 0.227  -      
C4.5+m+cf 0.062 0.999  0.170  

P value adjustment method: none
```

Can I get the critical value of 2.569 and the corresponding critical distance (CD) of 1.25 from somewhere?

How can I apply the Holm test?

(1) [Demšar, Janez. "Statistical comparisons of classifiers over multiple data sets." The Journal of Machine Learning Research 7 (2006): 1-30.](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/Demsar06.pdf)

Comment: I am struggling now with exactly the same story. Have you found the correct methods and packages in R?

Comment: I used python:
`crit_value = stats.f.isf(0.05,k-1,(k-1)*(m-1))`
`pval = stats.f.sf(FF,k-1,(k-1)*(m-1))*2`
`print 'ff-statistic = %.3f\npvalue = %.4f' % (FF, pval)`

`q = 2.291341`
`cd = q*np.sqrt( k*(k+1)/6.0/m )`
`print "The cirtical difference at alpha=0.10 is %.2f" % cd`